# can any grammatical rule show what is the right assertion being said here?

Tags: headlinese, attachment-ambiguity

in the headline:

> Giuliani’s Loyalty to Trump Was Born in His Darkest Moment

whose darkest moment is the author refering to, Trump's or Giuliani’s?

can that be answered just by reading this headline?

Comment: If this is a real headline, then you should cite the source. Some people also prefer for a link to be included (if it came from a website).

Comment: I downvoted your post for lack of source.

Comment: No, it cannot be answered by reading this headline

Answer (score 2):

The headline seems to be worded poorly, because the antecedent of "his" is ambiguous. The pronoun might refer to either "Giuliani" or "Trump".